# Find regex occurences of a set of patterns in correct order with Python

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing a series of text files for some patterns, since I want to extract them to other file.

A way to say it is that I would like to "remove" everything except the matches from the file.

For example, if I have pattern1, pattern2, pattern3 as matching patterns, I'd like the following input:

```
bla bla
pattern1
pattern2
bla bla bla
pattern1
pattern3
bla bla bla
pattern1
```

To give the following output:

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern1
pattern3
pattern1
```

I can use `re.findall` and successfully get the list of matches for any pattern, but I cannot think of a way to KEEP THE ORDER considering the matches of each pattern are mixed inside the file.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: wrote a copy-and-go solution based on @richards solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combine it all into a single pattern.  With your example code, use the pattern:

```
^pattern[0-9]+
```

If it's actually more complex, then try

```
^(aaaaa|bbbbb|ccccc|ddddd)
```

Comment: i dont think this works for OP, he has multiple matches in his REGEX that he looks for, "pattern1,pattern2,etc" are examples... see my answer.

Comment: I'll accept this answer, that's what I wanted to do, just didn't know how or didn't remember how. The multiple patterns using `|` (OR) is the key to get in order, cause it says "give me any match of the following patterns", and the result will then come already in order.

Comment: oh - i see what you did there now, yes, the second "more complex" regex would work. but OP should still use `file.writelines()` itterating over the list that `re.findall()` returns.

Comment: @InbarRose yeah, the full code needs to write stuff, my doubt was just about the pattern matching. Thanks everybody!

Comment: just for the record, my unholy pattern is: `'<p class="docText">.+?</p>|<h3 class="docSection1Title">.+?</h3>'` ;o)

Comment: @heltonbiker Have you not seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454? Do not try to parse HTML with regular expressions.

Comment: @AbeKarplus that's why it is "unholy". I know all of this, but for one-off site scraping without the need for REAL parsing, regexes have helped me a lot, even with the known limitations. That is, do not "count too much" on regexes to parse HTML (will I burn in hell?... ;o)

Comment: (that is, regex in this case is not used to "parse html", but to extract some very well behaved parts of a set of html files)

Answer (score 2):

here is an answer in "copy this and go" format.

```
import re

#lets you add more whenever you want
list_of_regex = [r"aaaa",r"bbbb",r"cccc"]

#hold the completed pattern
pattern_string = r"^("

#combines the patterns
for item in list_of_regex:
    pattern_string += "|".join(list_of_regex)

pattern_string += r")"

#open the file that you are reading
fr = open(FILE_TO_READ)

#holds the read files strings
search_string = fr.read()

#close the file
fr.close()

#open the file you want to write to
fw = open(FILE_TO_WRITE, 'w')

#write the results of findall into the file (as requested)
fw.writelines(re.findall(pattern_string,search_string))

#close the file
fw.close()
```

Comment: based off of @richards answer

Comment: I suspect `re.compile` could be of some help here, but I'd have to look more thoroughly. Thanks anyway!